# katalon studio, can't click a icon in a loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

```
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(3)
CustomKeywords.'userTable.sidebar.sidebarUsersClick'()

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Overview Page Objects/overview searchbar'), "Tester") //Search for the user.

List<WebElement> rows = WebUI.findWebElements(findTestObject('Object Repository/Overview Page Objects/patientList_Row'), 10) //create list from user results after search

for(int i = 1 ; i < rows.size() ; i++) {
    WebElement row = rows.get(i) //get the current row element
    WebElement firstCell = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@data-field='nameSurname']")) // get the text of the first cell (username and surname)
    String user = firstCell.getText()
    println user
        if(user.equals("QA Tester")) {
            WebElement deleteIcon = row.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Delete']"))
            deleteIcon.click()
            WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Users Page Objects/Add Patient Details/deleteButton'))
        }
}
```

[Username xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGEi.png)

[deleteicon xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOM9W.png)

Basicly in this code block. Firstly im searching a user name in searchbox, then make a List for the results of users, and creating loop for to find the user i want (QA Tester), then when loop finds the user i want, i want it to click the Delete Icon.
when i run this code. The loop ends successfully, but does not click the delete icon.

Comment: i think problem is in the If part but i cant fix it

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) {
    WebElement row = rows.get(i)
    WebElement firstCell = row.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@data-field='nameSurname']"))
    String user = firstCell.getText()
 println ">${user}<"

    if (user.contains("QA Tester")) {
        WebElement deleteIcon = row.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Delete']"))
        deleteIcon.click()
        WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Users Page Objects/Add Patient Details/deleteButton'))
  break
    }
}`
i used contains instead of equals its working now